# Spark Kyro buffer size limitations

Tags: java, jvm, apache-spark, bigdata

If I try to increase the spark.kryoserializer.buffer.mb to more than 1GB (1024), I get the following error.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
```

Note that my system has 128 GB of RAM, so there is plenty memory to have an array of bigger size than that. Is it because the serializer is using 32 bit indexing? How can we overcome this limitation? Or it could be that Java restricts array sizes to such limit. How can we tell Java to use a larger limit? And how can we specifically set it through Spark?